# best practices for declaring constants in VS 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I was recently told by my supervisor that ALL of the constants need to go in the Resources of our MVC application and I am to either put them there or into the database. I cannot find anywhere on Microsoft's website where this is stated. And secondly, there will eventually be dozens if not hundreds of constants in here.

The problem is we can't use them in switch statements and if I right click to go to definition it doesn't take me there. Which means if I want to change one I have to go search through the mess in Resources.

I always thought what went into the resources.resx were application specific.

I am used to putting constants that were specific to a certain controller in that controller. Global constants I would put into the Base class. Or create a constants class that holds all of the constants. I prefer the first

Can someone answer this question for me or point me to the location where it is stated that this is the new best practices?

Comment: Your approach to constant location is a good one. However, guess who wins between you and your supervisor. PS - How is your Skyline running these days?

Comment: Uhm, if your supervisor told you that it's a best practice ask him where did he read that, otherwise I don't know why you think everything your supervisor says is a best practice...

Comment: I don't agree with putting all constants into one file. We've had old projects that have one module (in vb) for hundreds of methods/properties, and it gets very messy. There should be a place for global variables (maybe the resources), but when they are only specific to a controller/class, that's where they belong.
Nice reference @Yuck

Comment: You _technically_ could create a `App.Resources` class library and place everything in there (then switch resources scope to `public`). I've seen that done before...

Comment: if a constant is a constant why not declare them in a base class? but i agree with @Yuck supervisor out pecks in pecking order!!! :-)

Comment: You could always point your supervisor towards, say [`Int32.MaxValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue.aspx), point out that it's a constant, and then enquire as to why, if it's a "standard practice" to put constants in resources, why Microsoft fail to do this in their own code.

Comment: What type of data is stored in the constants you should store in resources? Is it text which will be shown directly in your application?

Answer (score 6):

Resources are mainly for strings that needs to be localized and for additional data, such as icons, other images, or even textual *data* - but not for *code* just because that code happens to be a constant. In fact... the resource editing framework might very well auto-generate a constant in a code file to help you identify the resource. So you would essentially replace one constant with another.

I suspect your supervisor is either confused, or there have been a misunderstanding.